# What is the difference between sed 's/day/night/' < old > new and sed 's/day/night/' old > new

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

[Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) has this in [The essential command: s for substitution](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1):

> A simple example is changing "day" in the "old" file to "night" in the "new" file:
>
> ```
> sed s/day/night/ <old >new
> ```
>
> Or another way (for UNIX beginners),
>
> ```
> sed s/day/night/ old >new
> ```

What is the difference? Why does Bruce Barnett specify that one method is "for UNIX beginners"?

I can see that `old` is being used as input in both situations, and I can see that `new` is being used as output in both situations. Does the extra `<` make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice it doesn't change much. In fact the first variant limits you to one file while the second allows sed to concatenate several inputs to one output, as well as use its inplace editing option.

The technical difference is that the former method with `<` and `>` relies *exclusively* on shell redirection, a generic feature that Unix at first was famous for – due to its simplicity and being completely generic and reusable across many programs: the shell opens the file and hands you a file-descriptor.

(Other systems of the time either lacked redirection completely or required several commands to activate it.)

The latter also redirects output, but not input. Instead it asks sed *itself* to open the input file – something that every program has to implement on its own, possibly using inconsistent syntaxes which you'd have to learn and relearn; e.g. one tool might want `--input=original.txt --output=processed.txt` and another `-in original.txt`. But OTOH, as I mentioned, this is also more flexible in that you're not limited to one read-only input.

---

Personally, however, I would say that grouping the 2nd syntax under "...for Unix newbies" is just either 1980's elitism or pedantry, of the same kind as lecturing people for their use of `cat foo | bar` or making fun of Windows & VMS users for not being "enlightened to the Unix Philosophy".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Bruce is a "streamist", someone who believes in "everything is a stream of bytes" to the point where they consider passing files as parameters as something only beginners would want to do. A few reasons that I generally prefer the second way of doing things:

1. It is shorter.
2. It is syntactically simpler.
3. It allows using for example `-i[suffix]` to replace in-place without a whole lot of extra guff to swap files around.
4. It plays well with other tools such as `xargs`.